# Column '' does not exist error on existing and newly created lists. SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list, error, column

Any time a new item is added on a custom list, I get the error "Column '' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user". This is on a SharePoint 2013 farm. The problem originally started occurring with June 2013 CU (that had been running it for months before it started giving the error). I have since upgraded to SP1, June 2014 CU and all Windows Updates, but the problem still exists. The problem is occurring on both the test/QA site and the production site. I am not aware of any changes that triggered it, not even Windows Updates were installed in the time it stopped working.

The problem occurs any time you create a new item in lists that have been created for months and worked fine before, and it even occurs on newly created lists without any customization. Add an app, Custom List, Give it a name, Create, New Item, Save, error occurs.

Excerpt from verbose ULS logs:

```
Monitoring  abhd3   Verbose MonitoredScope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.AddItem is created in new Thread 54 where the parent Request (POST:https://testintra.mydomain.com:443/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery) is on 5  3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.AddItem). Parent Request (POST:https://testintra.mydomain.com:443/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery)   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM Api    agw12   Verbose Entering Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.AddItem    3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.AddItem). Execution Time=0.0984762029811051    3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____SQL Query Count=0   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____CPU Cycles=135376   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Execution Time=0.0984762029811051   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM Api    agw13   Verbose Leaving Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.AddItem 3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  abhd3   Verbose MonitoredScope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem is created in new Thread 54 where the parent Request (POST:https://testintra.mydomain.com:443/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery) is on 5   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem). Parent Request (POST:https://testintra.mydomain.com:443/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery)    3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM Api    agw12   Verbose Entering Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem 3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM    ahjq1   High    Exception occured in scope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem. Exception=System.ArgumentException: Column '' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Lists/Test     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem_Client(List`1 formValues, Boolean bNewDocumentUpdate, String checkInComment)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM    agmjp   High    Original error: System.ArgumentException: Column '' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Lists/Test     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem_Client(List`1 formValues, Boolean bNewDocumentUpdate, String checkInComment)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Microfeeds  aizmo   Medium  SocialRESTExceptionProcessingHandler.DoServerExceptionProcessing - SharePoint Server Exception [System.ArgumentException: Column '' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Lists/Test     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem_Client(List`1 formValues, Boolean bNewDocumentUpdate, String checkInComment)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)]   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Dev Events  ajfwk   Verbose BdcNotificationErrorHandler.TryGetErrorInformation -- IN    3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Dev Events  ajfwm   Verbose BdcNotificationErrorHandler.TryGetErrorInformation -- OUT. Not handling the error.  3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem). Execution Time=0.629130238619713  3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____SQL Query Count=0   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____CPU Cycles=1546708  3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Execution Time=0.629130238619713    3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM Api    agw13   Verbose Leaving Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem  3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
CSOM    2mx9    High    Ignore exception 'System.ArgumentException: Column '' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Lists/Test     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem_Client(List`1 formValues, Boolean bNewDocumentUpdate, String checkInComment)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement xe)' when executing '<ExceptionHandlingScopeSimple Id="10" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009"><Method Name="ValidateUpdateListItem" Id="12" ObjectPathId="8"><Parameters><Parameter Type="Array"><Object Type="Dictionary"><Property Name="$2M_1" Type="String">Title</Property><Property Name="$2N_1" Type="String">test</Property><Property Name="$j_1" Type="Null" /><Property Name="$2U_1" Type="Boolean">false</Property></Object><Object Type="Dictionary"><Property Name="$2M_1" Type="String">ContentType</Property><Property Name="$2N_1" Type="String">Item</Property><Property Name="$j_1" Type="Null" /><Property Name="$2U_1" Type="Boolean">false</Property></Object><Object Type="Dictionary"><Property Name="$2M_1" Type="String">ContentTypeId</Property><Property Name="$2N_1" Type="String">0x01006F8FC55B66F51C49A84B9CFCFA902FE6</Property><Property Name="$j_1" Type="Null" /><Property Name="$2U_1" Type="Boolean">false</Property></Object></Parameter><Parameter Type="Boolean">false</Parameter><Parameter Type="Null" /></Parameters></Method></ExceptionHandlingScopeSimple>'.   3ab69c9c-04c4-3005-8c98-870ae30114cc
```

The last line of this has some XML of what it is trying to save, it looks fine to me, it has 1 column "Title" and is using the "Item" content type. The Item content type just has the column "Title" and nothing else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExceptionHandlingScopeSimple xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" Id="10">
   <Method Name="ValidateUpdateListItem" Id="12" ObjectPathId="8">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Type="Array">
            <Object Type="Dictionary">
               <Property Name="$2M_1" Type="String">Title</Property>
               <Property Name="$2N_1" Type="String">test</Property>
               <Property Name="$j_1" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="$2U_1" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
            </Object>
            <Object Type="Dictionary">
               <Property Name="$2M_1" Type="String">ContentType</Property>
               <Property Name="$2N_1" Type="String">Item</Property>
               <Property Name="$j_1" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="$2U_1" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
            </Object>
            <Object Type="Dictionary">
               <Property Name="$2M_1" Type="String">ContentTypeId</Property>
               <Property Name="$2N_1" Type="String">0x01006F8FC55B66F51C49A84B9CFCFA902FE6</Property>
               <Property Name="$j_1" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="$2U_1" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
            </Object>
         </Parameter>
         <Parameter Type="Boolean">false</Parameter>
         <Parameter Type="Null" />
      </Parameters>
   </Method>
</ExceptionHandlingScopeSimple>
```

Comment: Some additional details to add to the confusion... If I go into SharePoint Designer and create a second/new "New Item Form", the new new form works just fine and the old one still gives the error message. Unfortunately since this is affecting every new and existing custom list/announcements/links/etc it is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: I have also restored a content DB containing a list that gives the error onto a different farm, and the list works fine. I have also created a new web application on the farm that has the error message, and lists inside the new web application work fine. I'm thinking there is something wrong with the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being because require.js was being loaded in the custom master page that was applied. I removed the  tag that was loading require.js and moved it into the webpart designer, everything works fine now. No idea why this was causing this error, but this fixed it 100%.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but require.js isn't being loaded in my custom master page. What steps led you to find the solution? Maybe the same steps will lead me to a different conclusion on my site.

Comment: Luckily there were only a few customizations in the master page, so the process of elimination found the problem for me. Do you have any <script> tags added at all? Try removing them for testing purposes, or change them over to <SharePoint:Scriptlink> tags. To make sure it is your master page causing this problem, try changing to an out of the box master page first.